# Lock excel cell after specific date

Tags: excel

I would like an excel cell to keep updating its value after a specific date has passed. How can I keep the cell from retrieving information after the date condition is met?

Comment: how is the cell  retrieving information now?

Comment: VBA and a `Workbook Open` event? When the workbook opens, check the date, and update if not past a specified date? What have you tried?

Comment: How often does the cell need to validate? What is the process for validation? Is this sheet constantly open or does it get saved/closed regularly?

Comment: it is updating by searching for values in tables and adding and subtracting values that finds. The thing is that I need it to do that for a month and then save the value after the month is finished. The sheet gets opened and closed regularly. I've tried using the condition that allows the cell to update during the month, the problem I'm currently encountering is that after the month I can't seem to be able to save the data and it goes back to 0 again.